# how to check using debugger whether program is written to file or not?

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb

I am using Ubuntu and am new to debugging. All I want is to check my simple file handling code in c++ is writing on a file or not. I am using gdb. How do I check whether the program is writing on file or not? for example, i want to debug this piece of code( which is erroneous, its not writing to file )

```
if(myfile)
{
    while(myfile>> total)
    {}
    cout << " Total : " << total << endl;

    cout << " PLz  donate : ";
    cin >> p; //Operator is Overloaded
    string s=p.returnDon();

    int tmp= stoi(s);

    total+=tmp;

    myfile << total;


}
```

Comment: IMHO, not the debugger but your program should check for success of every file operation. For this, all the C++ file I/O functions and classes have features which can tell you about success. Please, provide a [mcve] to make this a concrete question. Aside of this, you may have a look into doc. concerning error handling.

Comment: `gdb` is not suitable for this. You may use the command line utility `strace` for tracing which files are written by your program.

Comment: There are many ways to do that, but for your specific problem, I would use `strace -e file <your_program>` and check whether the syscalls related to that file end up with success.  You can do that with gdb as well, but it is a bit harder.  But I'm afraid you need to be a bit more specific if you want some answers.

Comment: How do i use strace

Comment: Read documentation of [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) and of [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)

Comment: by the way whats wrong with my code

Comment: Try to step inside debugger to `myfile << total` line of code. Probably you are not entering into `if` statement or go to infinite loop in `while(myfile>> total)`.

Comment: I debugged the snippet everything is just working fine, but i am not able to write into the file

Comment: See if this works: (a) place a breakpoint at the line after `myfile` is assigned. (b) start the program, run until that breakpoint. (c) type `(gdb) info inferior` to get the process id. (d) In a shell. do `ls -l /proc/theprocessid/fd` and look for the fd number that points to your file (e) type `(gdb) break write if ($rdi == thefdnumber)` (f) continue your program (g) when the write breakpoint is hit, type `(gdb) p (char *)$rsi` to see what's being written.

Comment: thanks @MarkPlotnick